# Git porcelain word diff with no newline at end of file

Tags: git

Usually when you do a normal `git diff` it shows you if the diff is missing a newline at the end like this

```
diff --git a/A b/A
index 08104ef..a3ba658 100644
--- a/A
+++ b/A
@@ -1 +1 @@
-this is A
\ No newline at end of file
+this is A2
```

If you do a word-diff porcelain output using `git diff --word-diff=porcelain --word-diff-regex=. --no-color` this information gets lost

```
diff --git a/A b/A
index 08104ef..a3ba658 100644
--- a/A
+++ b/A
@@ -1 +1 @@
 this is A
+2
~
```

Is there a way to include this info in a porcelain `diff` output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally no, since [`git diff --word-diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#git-diff---word-diffltmodegt) is focused on *words* differences.

Newline apparently is not considered a word in that use case.